# How to set other source to properties when set itemsource in the same template?

Tags: c#, wpf

When I want to get `ChartColor` from viewModel, it tries to find it in `BugsData` because I set `ItemsSource="{Binding BugsDataCollection}"`. Do you have a solution for me?

This is my code:

```
<Style x:Key="ColumnColor" TargetType="DVC:ColumnDataPoint">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ChartColor}"/>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ColumnSeriesTemplate">
    <DVC:Chart>
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <!--
            <DVC:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DVC:ColumnDataPoint}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ChartColor}" />
                </Style>
            </DVC:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
            -->
            <DVC:ColumnSeries DataPointStyle="{StaticResource ColumnColor}"
                    Title="{ComponentType}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding BugsDataCollection}"
                    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"></DVC:ColumnSeries>
        </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: It seems that the DataContext is not pointing to a viewmodel that exposes a ChartColor property. Try to change the DataContext to that of an element that does have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a relative source binding to access the data context of an element that’s higher-up in the hierachy and has access to your full view model:

```
<Setter Property="Background"
    Value="{Binding DataContext.ChartColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DVC:Chart}}}" />
```

Comment: I upload the user control that cantain this code dynmin, and I upload also the viewmodel dynamic, so I cann'd define the veiw modle in local resourses

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify source of the binding explicitely, because the default source (DataContext) points to wrong object (BugsData).

You can specify source by:

```
{Binding Source=...}
{Binding RelativeSource=...}
{Binding ElementName=...}
```

Try this:

```
 Value="{Binding DataContext.ChartColor, 
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DVC:Chart}}"
```

or you can try to add viewmodel to the usercontrol's resources and use staticresource to find the viewmodel:

```
 Value="{Binding DataContext.ChartColor, 
                 Source={StaticResouce MyViewModelResourceKey}}"
```

Comment: I upload the user control that cantain this code dynmin, and I upload also the viewmodel dynamic, so I cann'd define the veiw modle in local resourses